# Graph of a continuous function $f:M\to N$ is a closed subset of $M\times N$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, continuity

I need to prove that the graph of a continuous function $f:M\to N$ is a closed subset of $M\times N$. $N$ is a metric space. I think I'm supposed to use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1797525/f-x-in-m-f-lambdax-ge-0-forall-lambda-in-l-is-a-closed-subset-of-m). So, that's what I did:

$Graph(f) = \{(x,y)\in M\times N: y = f(x)\} = \{(x,y)\in M\times N: d(y,x)=0\} = \{z\in M\times N: f(z)=0\}$
which is a closed subset.

ps: I should use the fact that $d(y,x)$ is continuous. How to prove that? It's, in fact, the function $d(f(x), x)$.

Comment: What is your question actually? Is it the same as that in the title or is it what you have written as "ps"?

Comment: Are $M,N$ metric spaces?

Comment: @copper.hat yes

Comment: @user170039 I'd like to know if my proof is right and also how to prove my distance function is continuous

Comment: How do you define the distance on the product?

Comment: For this problem, you only need $N$ to be a metric space, $M$ can be any topological space. $M \times N$ should be assumed to have the product topology.

Comment: We are to show that if $d:Y×Y→\mathbb{R}$ is a metric on $Y$ then $d$ is continuous. To prove this let $(a,b)∈Y×Y$ and $((x_n,y_n))_{n∈N}∈Y×Y$ be any sequence converging to $(a,b)$. Then we have (by definition of convergence),
$|d(x_n,y_n)−d(a,b)|<ε$
for all sufficiently large $n∈N$. Which shows that $d$ is continuous.

Comment: To prove the inequality $|d(x_n,y_n)-d(a,b)|<\varepsilon$, you need to use the following two facts - (1.) $((x_n,y_n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $(a,b)$ implies $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $b$, (2.) $|d(x_n,y_n)-d(a,b)|\leqslant d(x_n,a)+d(y_n,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: If $N$ is a metric space, then the diagonal $\Delta_N = \{(y,y) \mid y \in N\}$ is a closed subset of the Cartesian product $N \times N$. (HINT: If $(y,z) \not \in \Delta_N$ then $d(y,z) =: d > 0$; then the Cartesian product of balls of radii $d/2$ centered at $y$ and $z$ respectively is an open set in the Cartesian product of $N$ with itself, and it does not intersect the diagonal.)

Note that this is a special case of the general result you want to prove - with $M = N$ and $f =$ the identity map of $N$, $f(y) = y\;$ for all $y\in N$.

Then, the function $M\times N \to N \times N, (x,y) \to (f(x), y)$ is continuous (use the definition of product topology), and the graph of $f$ is the pre-image through this continuous function of the diagonal of $N$. So the graph is a closed subset of $M\times N$.

**For extra credit:** The hypothesis that $N$ is a metric space is too strong. What property of metric spaces did we really use when we showed that the diagonal of $N$ is a closed subset of $N \times N$? *That* is the proper way to state the problem in its full generality. (In fact, a topological space $N$ has this property you must identify for extra credit, if and only if $\Delta_N$ is closed!)